# using the lisp application from AutoCAD with Python 3.5

Tags: python, lisp, autocad, gml, autolisp

I have 6000+ .gml files that hold the informations about cadastrial particles. I also have a .lsp application for AutoCAD (I didn't write the code) which reads the .gml file and draws the particle in .dxf file. The problem is that the application can only take one .gml file as an input so it's too much of a job doing it manually.

As I wrote the script to download those all .gml files from server in Python 3.5., I would like to know if there is a way to run the ACAD applications with Python, so I can loop through all the files and run the app? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

AutoCAD can be controlled by COM automation. Python can do this using [Mark Hammond's `pywin32` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) (despite the name, 64-bit builds are available).

You will end up with something like

```
import glob
import win32com.client

GML_FILES = r"c:\users\mario\documents\gml\*.gml"

# For other versions of AutoCAD see
# http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-0EDC04D5-2ACB-4555-B5AC-936D54A9FF61
acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application.22")   # AutoCAD 2018

for gml_file in glob.glob(GML_FILES):
    # I spent quite a while trying to fill this in,
    # but (a) the documentation is very short on examples,
    # and (b) I don't have a copy of AutoCAD
    # which makes it very hard to test - sorry!
```

You will want to refer to http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-86E44F95-2372-461D-862C-426038A6A24F

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called PyAutoCad which will help you with AutoCAD COM interaction. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyautocad/.
Installable with PIP:

```
pip install pyautocad
```

So your LISP script is callable as command. So i guess you are using

```
GMLIMPORT "PATHTOGML"
```

when your lisp script is called GMLIMPORT.
You could automate it this way

```
from pyautocad import Autocad
acad = Autocad()
for gml in gmls:
  acad.doc.SendCommand("GMLIMPORT " + gml)
```

This requires Autocad to be running. Check the pyautocad documentation to start autocad if not running.

Comment: I already solved it only with lisp language, but this information was really useful to know for other projects. Thank you!